Is the closure of Noetherian subring in a topological commutative ring also Noetherian?
Let $A$ be a topological commutative ring, and let $B$ be a subring of $A$. If $B$ is Noetherian, is it true that the topological closure $\overline{B}$ of $B$ in $A$ is also Noetherian?
Note that $\overline{B}$ is always a topological ring, and if $I$ is an ideal of $B$, then the closure $\overline{I}$ of $I$ in $A$ is an ideal in $A$. To show $\overline{B}$ is Noetherian, we need to show that it satisfies the ascending chain condition on ideals. But I can't even prove this for closed ideals. Thus, perhaps I should add the assumption that $A$ is a locally compact ring. Is that true in this case? Any references would be appreciated.

Can we maybe look at an interesting example first? Do you have one in mind? Not something basic like $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ whose closure is $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Consider $\mathbb R$ with the usual field structure and Euclidean topology.
This is a topological ring, hence each subring with the subspace topology is a topological ring.
Now let $A$ be any subring of $\mathbb R$, which contains $\mathbb Q$ and is not noetherian
(for instance, $\mathbb Q[x_1,x_2, ...]$, where $x_1,x_2, ...$ is pairwise distinct and a subset of a transcendence basis of $\mathbb R /  \mathbb Q$).
$\mathbb Q$ is a field, hence noetherian,
and $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $A$.
Note that $A$ cannot be locally compact, however.

With the last sentence, do you mean that the claim is true fo all locally compact topological rings?

@Martin Brandenburg: no, this I don't know. And in fact, I doubt, that this is true. I just wanted to indicate that this example is not a counter-example to the additional question of the PO.

Of course, if locally compact is defined without Hausdorff, there are trivial counter-examples. Just take any non-noetherian ring over $\mathbb Z$ with the indiscrete topology.
